# Help with error message "!Undefined control sequence.\namepartfamily -> R{\dbend}cker \end

Tags: biblatex, bibtex

I'm getting the error message "!Undefined control sequence.\namepartfamily -> R{\dbend}cker \end" and am lost in what it means. It comes up when I try to load my bibliography (I'm using biblatex with bibtex as my backend). My bibliography is created via the BetterBibTex extension from Zotero and every entry looks like this:

```
  title = {title},
  author = {Name, surname},
  year = {year},
  volume = {volume},
  pages = {page--page},
  doi = {doi},
  abstract = {abstract},
  journal = {xx},
  language = {xx},
  number = {xx}
}
```

Running from:

```
\documentclass[paper=a4,oneside,BCOR=10mm,DIV=calc,pagesize=auto,bibliography=totoc,listof=totoc,numbers=noenddot,chapterprefix=on]{scrbook}
\input{preambel/preambel.tex}

\begin{document}

\input{content/title.tex}
\input{content/content.tex}

\begin{flushleft}
\printbibliography
\end{flushleft}

\end{document}
```

I already tried looking for the sequence mentioned in the error message in my .bib but to no avail. I'd be happy for some insight on what could be my mistake! Hope I didn't miss anything!

Comment: Do you have `\usepackage{manfnt}` in your preamble?  It provides the `\dbend` definition.   That said, not sure why `\dbend` would appear in a bib entry, where on might otherwise expect an umlauted `u`.

Comment: Thanks a bunch! It worked!

Answer (score 3):

According to [The Comprehensive LaTeX Symbol List](http://mirrors.ctan.org/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf) `\dbend` is defined by the `manfnt` package. So you would load `\usepackage{manfnt}` to make `\dbend` work. See also [Steven B. Segletes](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/25858/steven-b-segletes) [comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/548826/help-with-error-message-undefined-control-sequence-namepartfamily-r-dbend#comment1386230_548826).

In this case it is, however, highly unlikely that `\dbend` is the actual command you are after. It looks more like an export/input error. Presumably the input to Zotero got messed up somehow (copy-and-paste encoding garbage) so that its (or Better BibTeX's) LaTeX converter now exports the wrong character. Double check your input for the relevant entries for non-ASCII chars.

Just for fun I Googled `\dbend` and found http://www.tg.uni-bonn.de/publications/talks/ where several German non-ASCII chars (`ä`, `ö`, `ß`) got converted to `\dbend` for some reason.

Comment: accents are dangerous things, need to be signposted:-)

Comment: BBT converts the unicode replacement character `\uFFFD` to `\dbend`. This is certainly an input error, the name in Zotero is `R�cker`, and the `\dbend` is just to signify that without aborting the export completely.

Answer (score 2):

The error message `"!Undefined control sequence.\namepartfamily -> R{\dbend}cker \end"` would seem to indicate `\dbend` is undefined.  The latter originates in the `manfnt` package and represents the double-dangerous bend used by Knuth in the TeXbook.  Place `\usepackage{manfnt}` in your preamble. It provides the `\dbend` definition.

That said, I am not sure why `\dbend` would appear in a bib entry, especially where on might otherwise expect an umlauted `u`, as in `R{\"u}cker`.  Presumably, `\dbend` appears in one of the bibliography entries.

The OP has indicated that this remedy fixed the issue.  The following MWE will generate the OP's error.

```
\documentclass[paper=a4,oneside,BCOR=10mm,DIV=calc,pagesize=auto,bibliography=totoc,listof=totoc,numbers=noenddot,chapterprefix=on]{scrbook}
\def\namepartfamily{R{\dbend}cker}
\begin{document}
\namepartfamily
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If you get `\dbend` from BBT, that means there's an unicode character `replacement character` (U+FFFD) in the name.